# WCF 4 Call Works with Cassini Not IIS

Tags: wcf, iis, authentication, authorization

I have a simple ASP.NET site making a call to a WCF service. The call works in Visual Studio 2010 (both sites running under Cassini using basic HTTP binding). Moving the same thing to XP , running the web site page (which makes a simple call to the WCF service) makes the web server throw a "500" error.

There is nothing in the Event Log.
Tracing is activated for the WCF service and everything looks normal except for a Warning-level message "Configuration evaluation context was not found." at the Open ServiceHost activity.

On the XP machine, there is just a single web site running as low IIS-in process with ASP.NET 4.0 set, also each Virtual Directory is set for ASP.NET 4.0, only anonymous auth is set on both vdirs (no Windows).

The web.config on the web site is set with Authentication set to "None" and identity impersonate is set to "false" as well.

I want the WCF service to be completely wide-open for this exercise, I just need it to take any call and return a result.

What am I missing?

Thanks.

Comment: Show us your server-side and your client-side config! How are you calling that service, what URL do you use??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A http 500 error means "internal error".

Your best bet to find what the error is, is to put a try catch around the call to the wcf service and log the error.

Also check the IIS log to verify that the call to the WCF service was made.

Comment: The WCF service was not using the "proper using" pattern that MS proscribes. Once that was done the error was found on the WCF side and not propagated to the front-end. It turns out the account impersonation/delegation Windows Domain policy was so locked down that MSSQL could not be queried. Changing to SQL auth in the connection string was the best (but not ideal IMHO) fix.